# Angular ngrx refreshes component on state change

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

I have an Angular app using ngrx to manage state. In the app footer I have a language switcher which uses a basic resolver to store the selected language value in localStorage:

```
export function locale(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_LOCALE':
      localStorage.setItem('xyz-locale', action.payload);
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return localStorage.getItem('xyz-locale') || 'en';
  }
};
```

The app uses the locale stored in localStorage to select the correct translations for the app, translations are also stored in app state with ngrx (but not saved to localStorage, this is just done on-the-fly).

Components (using the footer module as a child component) then subscribe to the translations and these are used in the component.

The problem is that when I switch language, it causes some of the members of the component's class to reset. This only happens in some circumstances and I am struggling to find the cause. So for example, if I have a component like this:

```
export class SomeComponent {
  public i18n: I18n;
  public data: Data;

  constructor(private store: Store<any>) {
    store.select('i18n').subscribe((i18n) => this.i18n = i18n);
  }
}
```

I can populate the data object fine, but if I switch the language in the footer, the data object is reset. I have no idea why it is doing this, and only sometimes. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: No idea what is wrong here but you can take a look at the angular-ngrx-material-starter project, which has this functionality - https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-ngrx-material-starter.

Comment: I assume from your example above `data` is local state for your component not coming from the store, are you sure you aren't making new instances of the component? There's nothing obvious in the above that might be causing this behaviour

Comment: Yes, data is a local variable, not connected to the scope. I assume something is happening that is re-rendering the component somehow but I am not sure what is causing it.

Comment: I know this is old, but adding `debugger` to the state-change-inducing function could maybe help you finding the cause ?